# Run Angular2 animations on item change

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I have the following code:

```
<item-detail [item]="selectedItem"[@flyInOut]="'in'"></item-detail>
```

Whenever the selectedItem changes, I want to make a smooth transition between the items.

I decided to try this from the docs:

```
animations: [
  trigger('flyInOut', [
    state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
    transition('void => *', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
      animate(100)
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate(100, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
    ])
  ])
]
```

but unfortunetly the animation wont trigger, seem like the item is not being removed from the view (void), but only changes.

Is there any way to set the animation to trigger when the item changes?